# Firefox keyboard shortcut or bookmarklet to control about:config value (to toggle javascript)

Tags: javascript, firefox

The [about:config flag "javascript.enabled"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994809) controls javascript in Firefox.

I am interested in a light-weight solution that will give me a quick way to toggle this value.

A keyboard shortcut or bookmarklet, for example, would be suitable.

Comment: The [PrefBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/prefbar/) add-on is generally very useful, and it has this feature. It's also got UserAgent control, Flash, REFERER, etc etc.

Comment: PrefBar is looking good so far. QuickJava fulfills the requirements above, but PrefBar gives many many more options which I'm also finding useful. Thanks Pointy.

Comment: I've been using PrefBar for years and years and it's super useful and, to my knowledge, it has never screwed up anything. Especially nice is the "Clear Cache" button.

Comment: @aaronbauman Good to hear that PrefBar is looking good for you :) If I need this same functionality, I'll look at PrefBar also.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out this Addon for Firefox:

[QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava/)

Just click the button to enable Javascript, Java and Flash - and you can choose which of the 3 you disable or enable when the button is clicked.