# Toggling JavaScript (on/off) in Firefox via keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, firefox, keyboard, firefox-addon

In Firefox, JavaScript is controlled by about:config parameter "javascript.enabled"

How can I toggle this value with a **keyboard combination**?

(there are extensions doing it via GUI manipulations; this is not what I am looking for. Installing an extension to be able to run keyboard combinations is fine)

This question is related, but not identical, to [Firefox keyboard shortcut or bookmarklet to control about:config value (to toggle javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807887/firefox-keyboard-shortcut-or-bookmarklet-to-control-aboutconfig-value-to-toggl)

And it would be particularly nice to [toggle JavaScript and immediately reload the page] with the same keyboard combination. Reloading is possible e.g. with Cmd-R on OSX.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: The solution can be programmatic or indeed a tool. I don't mind moving this to Super User though if it seems to fit better.

Comment: What type of question it is depends on how you word it. If you are just looking for an add-on to install, then it does not belong here. If you are looking for a solution that involves you programming, then it could belong here, but is a bit broad (it is at least 2 questions). You basically already have all the code as examples. You have add-ons which perform the task, but by GUI, and you have questions/answers about adding a keyboard shortcut to Firefox (or add-ons that do so). What you desire is a synthesis of the two things for which you already have access to source code examples.